# Grab specific info from database with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a table such as:

info_name | info_value

name | Susan

desc      | Human

how would I grab and display Susan with PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: -1, StackOverflow is really a place to get help on code you've already tried. If you need PHP programming tutorials on getting data from a MySQL database Google is your best start.

Comment: Also, do not structure your tables as key-value pairs like that. Have meaningful columns with meaningful data types. You'll be *much* happier down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * from info_table where info_name = 'Susan'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
//given that there could be more than one 'Susan'
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo $row['info_name'] . " " . $row['info_value'] . "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php.
Basically your php script will connect to database, execute a query to get "susan" data then you will have to print out the data with php.